# "Enable Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert" not appearing, why?

Tags: lead-conversion, setup

Under what circumstances will the "Enable Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert" setting not appear in the Setup > Customize > Leads > Settings page?

We did a customer install into an EE org and I was surprised to see that this option was not visible to their admin profiles. I've not seen this before, and could not find any reference in documentation to why it would not appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible reason can be is that, this feature was released in spring '08. If your production org is created before this release then this feature won't we available by default. You need to contact salesforce to enable this feature.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds correct, hadn't seen it before. Do you happen to know - if this feature is not "enabled", does this mean that validation/triggers always fire from conversion, or never fire?

Comment: They never fire actually. During lead conversion before insert, before update, validation rules,  workflow on Account, contact, opportunity don't get fired when this feature not enabled.