# Populate Lookup field on Opportunity upon Lead Conversion

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

I am trying to populate a Contact lookup field (Sourced_By__c) on the Opportunity with the Converted Contact upon Lead Conversion but am not having any luck. I do not get an error but it also does not populate the field. Here is my trigger below, can anyone help?

```
Trigger Lead on Lead (before update) {

    if (Trigger.isBefore) {

        if (Trigger.isUpdate) { 

            Set<Id> setLeadIds     = new Set<Id>();  
            Set<Id> setConvertedOppIds   = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> setConvertedContIds   = new Set<Id>();  

            for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) {

                // Find all converted Leads with Opportunitiy and add ConvertedOpportunityId to setConvertedOppIds
                if (ld.isConverted && ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null 
                    && Trigger.oldMap.get(ld.Id).ConvertedOpportunityId != ld.ConvertedOpportunityId) 
                    setConvertedOppIds.add(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId);  

                 // Find all converted Leads with Contacts and add ConvertedContactId to setConvertedContIds    
                if (ld.isConverted && ld.ConvertedContactId != null 
                    && Trigger.oldMap.get(ld.Id).ConvertedContactId != ld.ConvertedContactId) 
                    setConvertedContIds.add(ld.ConvertedContactId);         
            }  

       if (!setConvertedOppIds.isEmpty()) {

                List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
                for(Opportunity opps:[select Id,AccountId,CampaignId from Opportunity where Id in :setConvertedOppIds])

                List<Contact> lstCont = new List<Contact>();
                for(Contact Conts:[select Id,AccountId from Contact where Id in :setConvertedContIds])

                  if (lstOpp.size() > 0) {                  
                    for (Opportunity opp : lstOpp) {
                        Opportunity otm = new Opportunity(
                                   //OpportunityId  = opps.Id,
                                   Sourced_By__c  = Conts.Id);
                        lstOpp.add(otm);
                    }
                                        if (!lstOpp.isEmpty()) {Update lstOpp;
                                               }


            }
        }       
    }   
}
   }
```

Comment: Is the Enforce Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert setting checked under Setup -> Customize -> Lead -> Settings?

Comment: I don't even have a setting for that, when I go under Setup -> Customize -> Lead -> Settings I only see: "Do Not Change Lead Status Values to New Owner's Record Type on Lead Conversion" and the Queue settings.

Comment: If you think that is the problem I will submit a case to have that feature enabled since it seems our org is older than when that feature was created. See notes here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/enable-validation-and-triggers-from-lead-convert-not-appearing-why

Comment: Ah, that could be the start of the problem then. Unless you need the trigger to be in a Before context, which I don't think you do from the code above, you can just switch it to an After context, which will execute without the setting above being enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Trigger Lead on Lead (after update) {

    if (Trigger.isAfter) {

        if (Trigger.isUpdate) { 

            Map<ID,ID> oppToContact = new Map<ID,ID>(); 

            for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) {
                if(ld.isConverted && trigger.oldMap.get(ld.id).isConverted) continue; //only process newly converted leads

                // Find all converted Leads with Opportunitiy and add ConvertedOpportunityId to setConvertedOppIds
                if (ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null && ld.ConvertedContactId != null){                    
                    oppToContact.put(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId,ld.ConvertedContactID);  

                }

            }  

       if (!oppToContact.isEmpty()) {

                List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
                for(Opportunity opps:[select Id,AccountId,CampaignId from Opportunity where Id in :oppToContact.keySet()]){

                    if(oppToContact.containsKey(opps.id)){
                        opps.Sourced_By__c = oppToContact.get(opps.id);
                        lstOpp.add(opps);
                    }

                }
        }

        if (!lstOpp.isEmpty()) {
          Update lstOpp;
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plus 1 for Eric's answer.

Depending on your requirements, you might be able to simplify it a bit and save a SOQL query in the trigger context.

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after update) {

    if (trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) {
        List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

        for (Lead ld : triggerNew) {
            if(ld.isConverted && triggerOldMap.get(ld.id).isConverted) {
                continue; //only process newly converted leads
            }

            if (ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null && ld.ConvertedContactId != null) {
                 Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Id = ld.ConvertedOpportunityId);
                 opp.Sourced_By__c = ld.ConvertedContactID;
                 oppsToUpdate.add(opp);
            }
        }

        if (!oppsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update oppsToUpdate;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by Process builder also.

Define criteria:

[Lead].Isconverted equals boolean false
[Lead].ConvertedOpportunityId isnull boolean false

(I wanted this to run only when opportunity needs to be created if you have any other things to do while conversion then you can remove the opportunity check and place the conditions in immediate action)

Immediate actions:
[image: Please check the image]

You can easily do it with clicks and no code needed.