# I have 2 lookup fields in Lead for 2 different custom objects. I want to map both of them to 2 Opportunity custom fields upon Lead conversion

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

Brands__c , Corporate__c are two custom object. I have two look-up fields in Lead form to set Lead's Brand and Corporate Just as Account and Contact. Now I want to move both fields to opportunity upon Lead conversion. I tried maping but it did't work in my case.
I am trying to get this with a simple trigger and will pass both values to (future = true) method where i'll perform desired operations.
there is a solution  [Populate Lookup field on Opportunity upon Lead Conversion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36602/populate-lookup-field-on-opportunity-upon-lead-conversion)
But it dos'nt work for me.
Any input will be highly appreciated.

Here I got Id's for both, Brand and Corporate, But I want to past the relevant information in Opportunity upon Lead conversion. I'm serializing it because i have pass it to future=true mthod where i need to generate unique code using these three codes and save them in a separate object.

```
trigger Lead_Field_to_Opp on Lead (before update) {

List<Lead> lead_BrCor = new List<Lead>();
for(Lead lead: trigger.new)
 {
    if(lead.IsConverted)
    { 
        lead_BrCor = [Select Brand_Name__c, Branchs_Corporate_Name__c From Lead WHERE id=:lead.Id];
        String ID_opp = JSON.serialize(lead_BrCor);
        system.debug('Brand & Corporate JSON serialized ::::' +ID_opp);
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mind putting your trigger code here?  It could just be a slight error in your algorithm

Comment: hi @BrianMiller I have updated the stack body with trigger code as well. check it.

Comment: You should use a `after update` context - the lead isn't actually converted until after the transaction runs