# Restrict converting lead is user is not owner

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

I have validation rule and trigger where i need to restrict users from converting lead if they are not the owners, both of them doesn't seems to work..what was the issue?

**Validation rule:**

```
AND(
IsConverted = TRUE,
OwnerId != $User.Id
)
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger leadPreventer on Lead (before insert, before update)
  {
    if(trigger.isUpdate)
     {
       for(Lead l:Trigger.new)       
        {       
           if (l.IsConverted && UserInfo.getUserId()!=l.OwnerId)       
            {           
              l.addError('Its not possible');
            }       
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding debug statements to your trigger to verify the values?

Comment: Agree with @MikeChale. Debug statements inside the for loop and a log after this is run would be very helpful to see.

Comment: You tried these individually, right?  They were not both active  at the same time.

Comment: I haven't added any debug statements since i thought it's pretty straightforward but i will check on that.

Comment: @Jagular. Yes i did and it doesn't works either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the validation rule it looks like you might have Lead conversion setting as unchecked.

If you go to Setup - Customize - Leads - Settings and check if "Enforce Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert" is checked or not.

Ideally if it is unchecked then Validation Rule and Triggers on Lead conversion will be ignored.

Update: Since you cannot enable "Enforce Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert" in your org, due to your org being an old one as rightly pointed out by @Jenny B.

You can get these settings to be displayed from salesforce, or add your custom button on Lead for conversion and gracefully decline a conversion if initiated by user other than record owner.
If the user who clicks on your convert button is the owner of lead record then forward him to convert lead page ( which is https://na10.salesforce.com/lead/leadconvert.jsp?id={!Lead.ID}), else throw an alert message.

Comment: When i go to lead settings i don't see that, i only see these 2 options  Preserve Lead Status and Enable Conversions on the Salesforce1 App

Comment: @Admin_BA not sure how old your org is, but according to this answer, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/enable-validation-and-triggers-from-lead-convert-not-appearing-why/16063#16063, you may need to have salesforce enable it if you have an older org.

Answer (score 0):

Please check  this  validation rule:

```
IsConverted =True && $User.Id <> OwnerId
```

I hope it will  work.