# Disable task trigger on lead conversion

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion

I wrote triggers that will be fired after inserting/updating/deleting task and event. What the triggers do is HTTP call out. When a lead is convert, tasks and events will be copied too, so the triggers are fired and give a "too many future task" exception.

After discussing with my project manager, we decided that, on lead conversion, copying tasks and events *is required* but the HTTP callout triggers are not.

I don't want the triggers to be fired on lead conversion. What should I do? Or how could the task/event trigger check that a user is converting a lead.

According to this page [Understanding Lead Conversion](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_notes.htm&language=en_US) I tried disabling validation and triggers for lead convert. But the task and event triggers were still fired. (I think only lead/account/contact/opportunity's trigger were disabled.)

Any help would be appreciated.

---

My solution:

According to [this page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/lead-conversion-trigger-order-of-execution), I think, when a lead is converted, an account/contact/opportunity will be created before lead.InConverted is changed to true. I tried creating triggers to test the conversion flow. The test result shown below.

Trigger on Account is fired.
Triggers on Task/Event are fired.
Trigger on Lead is fired.

So, I create a class which contains only a static boolean like checkLeadConvertIsInProgress == false. And in a trigger on Account, I set checkLeadConvertIsInProgress == true.

When the trigger on Task is fired, the trigger will check on checkLeadConvertIsInProgress, if true, skip the HTTP callout, otherwise do the callout.

Thank you for all your helps!

Comment: So you are copying tasks and events from Lead to become tasks/events under Account/Contact/Oppo ?  If so, then the DML that does the copy can set a custom field in Task object: `is_originated_from_lead_conversion__c` and your Task trigger code can skip doing its work if this is true (you'll have to decide how to deal with subsequent DML at a later time on same Task and whether trigger work is disabled as well.

Comment: You could use a Trigger on Lead that checks for IsConverted==True. Then when Tasks or Events are being triggered for the corresponding Contact you could bypass the trigger in the same transaction. Set a static boolean in a class that can be used to indicate the lead conversion is in progress.

Comment: @crop1645 Thank you! I think I have the idea how to do it. And then the task/event trigger after insert can switch is_originated_from_lead_conversion__c to fault later.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thank you. I will look into IsConverted and the use of static boolean. Great advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Trigger on Lead that checks for [`IsConverted`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm#i1452531) `== true`. Then when Tasks or Events are being triggered for the corresponding Contact you could bypass the trigger in the same transaction. Set a static boolean in a class that can be used to indicate the lead conversion is in progress.

Comment: May I ask when lead.IsConverted is set to true? I tried writing a trigger on lead before update but the trigger on task after update is fired before the trigger on lead.

Comment: Thank you again. I solved the problem using your advice. :)

Comment: Great, how did you get round the IsConverted not being set until after update?

Comment: I added the solution to my post. I use the static boolean variable as you told me, and set it to true after an Account is created so I can pass the variable to the following trigger process on task creation.