# Help writing a Lead trigger to create an OpportunityContactRole when lead is converted

Tags: trigger

This is actually a continuation of https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000CkWa.

I'm looking to write a trigger that will run when a Lead is converted.

The trigger should create an OpportunityContactRole like this:
    OpportunityId:   Lead.ConvertedOpportunityId
    ContactId:       Lead.ConvertedContactId
    IsPrimary:      TRUE

I'd greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you need this? when I did this on my org, SFDC automatically created an OCR with isPrimary = true between the contact and the opportunity

Comment: Good point - I just double checked, and it looks like the Contact Role is being created. In that case, I can't figure out what the issue is here. I have a trigger that runs when an Opportunity record is created or updated, but it doesn't run when on Opps that are created by the conversion process. Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/09d02f388683179319fb. Do you think you can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

First off

Are you sure you need this? when I did this on my org, SFDC automatically created an OCR with isPrimary = true between the contact and the opportunity

Secondly, triggers on Account, Contact, Opportunity won't execute on Lead Conversion unless the checkbox `Require Validation for Converted Leads` in Setup | Customize Lead | Settings is checked. Note this is an all-or-nothing thing; if these triggers will throw validation errors, the Lead won't convert

For more great info on Lead Conversion triggers - see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3961/2602

Comment: Thanks for answering. That checkbox is already checked off. Anything else that could be preventing the trigger from running?

Comment: Your trigger has two issues:  1: there won't be any OCR when the Oppo trigger fires.  The lead convert process will add the OCR after the Oppo has been inserted. 2: you have soql inside a for loop which means the trigger is not bulkified.  See apex dev doc for how to bulkify a trigger

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll work on one issue at a time. Do you think if I switch the trigger to be 'after insert', it'll fix the issue of not having the OCRs?

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3961/2602 - it will tell you that you have to write the trigger as after update on Lead, not on Opportunity - both Opportunity and Contact have to be fully created before SFDC can insert the OCR

Comment: I see - so I need a separate trigger that does the same thing, for when leads are converted. I'll work on that.

Comment: yes -- looks like you are trying to populate a lookup field in Opportunity with the primary contact. this can be done with an after update trigger on Lead -- look at SFDC Object doc to see which lead fields you will need to locate the converted oppo