# How to map lead custom field with Standard Account field 'Parent Account'

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup

I have a requirement inwhich I have to create a custom lookup field on lead object which selects the account and during the lead to account conversion I have to map the field with 'Parent Account' field of the account which is a standard field.with the help of Standard Mapping it is not possible.So i am trying to write the code on before insert trigger that maps the custom lookup field of lead to the standard field of account.

```
Code:

 public void beforeInsert(SObject so) {

        Account newAccount = (Account)so;
if(newAccount<>null)
        {
            List<Lead> convertedLeads=[SELECT Id, ConvertedAccountID, Parent__c FROM Lead WHERE IsConverted=True AND ConvertedAccountId <>NULL]; 
            Map<ID,ID> acctMap=new Map<ID,ID>(); 
            List<Account> acc=[Select Id,ParentId from Account where Id=:newAccount.Id Limit 1];
            for (lead l: convertedLeads)
            { 
            acctMap.put(l.ConvertedAccountId,l.Parent__c); 
            } 
            for (account a:acc)
            { 
            if (acctMap.containsKey(a.Id))
            { 
            a.ParentId=acctMap.get(a.Id); 
            } 
            } 


        }

}
```

but unfortunately it does not map the lead field with account.Can you please suggest what i am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do a **after update on Lead** Trigger. This is due to order of execution on Lead conversion. You can find some information here :
[Lead Conversion Trigger Order of Execution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/lead-conversion-trigger-order-of-execution)

Then you have to check isConverted has changed. There you can take the field in trigger.new and move it to the account by using ConvertedAccountId. I paste some code I used to do something similar.

In this example you can see I map Leadsource Into accountSource, Description && other fields among creating other objects.

```
public without sharing class TriggerLeadConversionEvents implements Triggers.Handler{

    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,List <Ga_Traffic__c>> MapTraffics = new Map<Id,List <Ga_Traffic__c>> ();
    Map<Id,Id> leadAccount = new Map<Id,Id>();
    Map<Id,Lead> accountsToCheck = new Map<Id,Lead>();

    public void handle(){

        Map<Id,Lead> oldMap = (Map<Id,Lead>) trigger.oldMap;    
        for (Lead l : (List<Lead>) trigger.new){
            if(l.isConverted != oldMap.get(l.id).isConverted){
                if(l.convertedAccountId != null){
                    contactIds.add(l.ConvertedContactId);
                    accountsToCheck.put(l.ConvertedAccountId, new Lead(BDM_MRR__c = l.BDM_MRR__c,LeadSource = l.LeadSource, Description = l.Description));
                    leadAccount.put(l.Id,l.ConvertedAccountId);
                } 
            }
        }
        for(Ga_Traffic__c GA:[SELECT id,Lead__c,Account__c FROM Ga_Traffic__c WHERE Lead__c in: leadAccount.keySet()]) {
            List <Ga_Traffic__c> TrafficsOfGALead = MapTraffics.get(GA.lead__c);
            if(TrafficsOfGALead==NULL) TrafficsOfGALead = new List <Ga_Traffic__c> {GA};
            else  TrafficsOfGALead.add(GA);
            MapTraffics.put(GA.Lead__c,TrafficsOfGALead);
        }

        if(accountsToCheck.keySet().size()>0){
            List<sObject> recordsToUpdate = new List<sObject>();     
            for (Account acc : [SELECT Id, AccountSource FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountsToCheck.keySet()]){
                if(accountsToCheck.get(acc.Id)!=null && (acc.AccountSource == null || acc.AccountSource == '')){
                    recordsToUpdate.add(new Account(BDM_MRR__c = accountsToCheck.get(acc.id).BDM_MRR__c,Id=acc.Id, AccountSource=accountsToCheck.get(acc.Id).LeadSource, Description =accountsToCheck.get(acc.Id).Description));
                } 
            }

            for(Event ev : [SELECT Id, Demo_Status__c 
                            FROM Event 
                            WHERE Demo_status__c='Scheduled' 
                            AND WhoId IN :contactIds 
                            AND Type IN ('Web Demo','Meeting + Demo')]){
                ev.Demo_Status__c = 'Completed';                
                recordsToUpdate.add(ev);
            }
            for(Ga_Traffic__c GA: [SELECT Lead__c,Account__c FROM Ga_Traffic__c WHERE Lead__c in: leadAccount.keySet()]) {
                GA.Account__c = leadAccount.get(GA.lead__c);
                recordsToUpdate.add(GA);
            }
            if(recordsToUpdate.size()>0){
                update recordsToUpdate;
            } 

            List<AccountCampaignMember__c> acmToUpsert = new List<AccountCampaignMember__c>();
            for(CampaignMember cm : [SELECT LeadId, CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadId IN :leadAccount.keySet()]){
                acmToUpsert.add(new AccountCampaignMember__c(CampaignRef__c = cm.CampaignId, AccountRef__c = leadAccount.get(cm.LeadId), UniqueKey__c = String.valueOf(leadAccount.get(cm.LeadId)) + cm.CampaignId));
            }           
            if(!acmToUpsert.isEmpty()){
                upsert acmToUpsert UniqueKey__c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much..I have modified the code and mapping is done to account from lead