# OpportunityContactRole Query returning Empty List

Tags: lead-conversion, opportunitycontactrole

I used a Query on OpportunityContactRole in Opportunity Trigger.

```
for(OpportunityContactRole c: [SELECT Id, opportunityid, contactId FROM
         OpportunityContactRole where opportunityid in: newOpp]){
```

It returns a list when I create and Opportunity from Contact Record Page. But when an Opportunity is created via Lead Conversion this query is Returning Empty List. But after the Lead Conversion, the newly created Opportunity have the Contact Role assigned to it.

Why the OpportunityContactRoles is empty?

TIA

Comment: Have you checked if the Opportunity Trigger is firing when an Opportunity is being created via Lead Conversion? For triggers to fire on Opportunities and Accounts on Lead Conversion you need to enable "Enforce Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert".

Comment: The trigger is working fine. Now as per @sfdcfox, Opportunity Contact Role records don't exist when the opportunity is created during the lead conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Opportunity Contact Role records don't exist when the opportunity is created during the lead conversion process (as outlined in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3961)). Anything you want to do *during* the lead conversion process must be done in the Lead After Update trigger, instead. You will probably want to write a utility class and a method so you can call the same logic from two different triggers.

Comment: Great. To resolve this issue we had to write the code in Lead After Update. worked like charm :)