# Trigger on Lead Object not working

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement in which I have to create a custom lookup field on lead object which selects the account 
`Account__c` and during the lead to account conversion I have to map the field with 'Parent Account' field of 
the account which is a standard field.So i am trying to write the code 
on before insert trigger that maps the custom lookup field of lead to the standard field of account.

```
trigger populateParentAccount on Lead(after Update) {
    List<Account> newAccList = (List<Account>)Trigger.New;
      List<Account> updateAccontList = new List<Account>();
      Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();  
system.debug('newAccList: ' + newAccList);    
      for(Lead record: [SELECT ConvertedAccountId, Agency_Account__c FROM Lead WHERE ConvertedAccountId = :newAccList]) {
        // Avoid multiple leads with same account 
        system.debug('ConvertedAccountId:' + record.ConvertedAccountId);
        system.debug('record:' + record);
        if(!accountIds.contains(record.ConvertedAccountId)) { 
          updateAccontList.add(new Account(Id=record.ConvertedAccountId, ParentId=record.Agency_Account__c));
          accountIds.add(record.ConvertedAccountId);        }
      }
      if(!updateAccontList.isEmpty()){
          update updateAccontList;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question [Map lead custom field (Account\_\_c) with Standard Account field 'Parent Account'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291043/map-lead-custom-field-account-c-with-standard-account-field-parent-account)

Comment: No Derek, It is on Lead and it is after update Trigger.