# How to get the Lead Record using ConvertedContactId field in after Insert Trigger on Contact?

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion, after-trigger, recordtriggeredflow

**Scenario:** I have a Lead record and it's single child record.
On this child record of Lead I have a look up of Contact and Account also.

Whenever a Lead is converted to Account and Contact, I want to map that Account and Contact on the child record of Lead.

I'm writing a trigger on Contact in after Insert Context as below.
But I'm not able to get the Lead Record using the ContactId in this Trigger.
I have also tried doing it using flow, but it gives the same issue.

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
        set<string> setContactId = new set<string>();
        List<Lead> lstLead = new List<Lead>();
        List<Child_Object__c> lstCh = new List<Child_Object__c>();
        List<Child_Object__c> lstChToUpdate = new List<Child_Object__c>();
        
        for(Contact objCon:Trigger.new){
            if(objCon.Converted_from_Lead__c == true){
                setContactId.add(objCon.Id);
            }
        }
        system.debug('setContactId--'+setContactId); // I get the contact Id here
        
        Map<string,Lead> mapIdAndLead = new Map<string,Lead>();
        
        if(setContactId != null && setContactId.size() > 0){
            lstLead = [select id,Name,MobilePhone,Status,IsConverted,ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId,ConvertedContact.Name 
                       from Lead 
                       where ConvertedContactId =: setContactId]; // I don't get the lead record here so nothing proceeds further
        }
        
        if(lstLead != null && lstLead.size() > 0){
            for(Lead objLd:lstLead){
                mapIdAndLead.put(objLd.Id,objLd);
            }
            
            lstCh = [select Id,Name,Lead__c,Contact__c,Account__c from Child_Object__c where Lead__c =: mapIdAndLead.keySet()];
            
            for(Child_Object__c objCh:lstCh){
                if(mapIdAndLead.containsKey(objCh.Lead__c)){
                    Lead objLead = mapIdAndLead.get(objCh.Lead__c);
                    objCh.Contact__c = objLead.ConvertedContactId;
                    objCh.Account__c = objLead.ConvertedAccountId;
                    lstChToUpdate.add(objCh);
                }
            }

            if(lstChToUpdate != null && lstChToUpdate.size() > 0){
                update lstChToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PS. `lstChToUpdate` is never null, as a query cannot be a null object, and `lstChToUpdate.size() > 0` is unnecessary, as the DML operations do this for you anyways (to avoid wasting governor limits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the trigger on the Lead object. The lead trigger fires after the Account, Contact, and Opportunity records have had their triggers executed. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3961/2984). As a bonus, you get this action for free, so you don't need to do any queries at all.